# Insert INTO Temp Table result of dynamic query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to write an SQL Server stored procedure in PostgreSQL. 
One of the statement is, `INSERT INTO @TempTable EXEC(@DynamicQuery)`
In SQL Server, `@DynamicQuery` executes and inserts result into @TempTable table variable. I am not finding similar option in PostgreSQL. Can somebody help with any hint please. Thanks.

Comment: HINT:  `create table as`

Comment: Will it work with dynamic query with EXECUTE()?

Answer (score 5):

Your PL/pgSQL line would look similar to the following:

```
EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mytemp AS ' || dynamicquery;
```